# Remove substring from a list of strings

Tags: c#, regex, linq, list, replace

I have a list of strings that contain banned words. What's an efficient way of checking if a string contains any of the banned words and removing it from the string? At the moment, I have this:

```
cleaned = String.Join(" ", str.Split().Where(b => !bannedWords.Contains(b,
                            StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToArray());
```

This works fine for single banned words, but not for phrases (e.g. `more than one word`). Any instance of `more than one word` should also be removed. An alternative I thought of trying is to use the List's Contains method, but that only returns a bool and not an index of the matching word. If I could get an index of the matching word, I could just use `String.Replace(bannedWords[i],"");`

Comment: Efficient in what way? Performance? Code length?

Comment: The problem boils down to a simple find-and-replace, until you make the clbuttic mistake: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx

Comment: what's wrong with your solution in regards to 'more than one word' - if it's overlapping you can sort them by length, bigger to smaller? More efficient would be to 'enumerate' through - but you'd still have to be careful of 'overlaps'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `String.Replace` will not work as it will remove word parts. If "sex" is a banned word and you have the word "sextet", which is not banned, you should keep it as is.

Using `Regex` you can find whole words and phrases in a text with

```
string text = "A sextet is a musical composition for six instruments or voices.".
string word = "sex";
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"\b" + word + @"\b");
```

The matches collection will be empty in this case.

You can use the `Regex.Replace` method

```
foreach (string word in bannedWords) {
    text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\b" + word + @"\b", "")
}
```

`\b` stands for word beginnings and ends. I first had a solution using regex lookaheads and lookbehinds; however, this is not necessary for `\b` as it is  of zero length.

If your banned words or phrases can contain special characters, it would be safer to escape them with `Regex.Escape(word)`.

---

Using @zmbq's idea you could create a `Regex` pattern once with

```
string pattern =
    @"\b(" +
    String.Join(
        "|",
        bannedWords
            .Select(w => Regex.Escape(w))
            .ToArray()) +
     @")\b";
var regex = new Regex(pattern); // Is compiled by default
```

and then apply it repeatedly to different texts with

```
string result = regex.Replace(text, "");
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the best method, but I noticed that whole words are not being matched. I have `x y zs`, and I search for `x y z` (match should not be found since it's `x y zs`), but a match is found and it removes `x y z`, but leaves the `s`. Might be a mistake on my part but it should match the entire phrase.

Comment: Did you note that I added parentheses in `@"(?<=\b)("` and `@")(?=\b)"`? The resulting pattern should be `(?<=\b)(word1|word2|word3)(?=\b)`

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you have conflicting definitions.

When you want to look for sub-sentences like `more than one word` you cannot split on whitespace anymore. You'll have to fall back on `String.IndexOf()`

Answer (score 2):

If it's performance you're after, I assume you're not worried about one-time setup time, but rather about continuous performance. So I'd build one huge regular expression containing all the banned expressions and make sure it's compiled - that's as a setup.

Then I'd try to match it against the text, and replace every match with a blank or whatever you want to replace it with.

The reason for this, is that a big regular expression should compile into something comparable to the finite state automaton you would create by hand to handle this problem, so it should run quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you iterate through the list of banned words and look up each of them in the string by using the method `string.IndexOf`.
For example, you can remove the banned words and phrases with the following piece of code:

```
myForbWords.ForEach(delegate(string item) {
    int occ = str.IndexOf(item);
    if(occ > -1) str = str.Remove(occ, item.Length);
});
```

Type of myForbWords is `List<string>`.

Comment: This seems to match partial words instead of whole words. So if I try and replace `turn`, it will change `turning` into `ing` but it shouldn't affect `turning` since that's not the word I wanted to replace.

Comment: That's right. I missed that. As you pointed out, that may happen. So checking the following character which comes right after occ (the occurence) whether it's a alphanumeric and numeric character or not fixes this issue.