# C# - Find and remove substring from a list of strings

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a bad word list. If a string contains any of item/items from the bad word list, I need to remove that bad word from the string.

```
List<string> badWordList = new List<string> { "email:", "index", "mobile:", "fax:", "web" };
```

I am able to search the string but not able to remove. Please help me out...I tried below code:

```
string myText = "email:abc@gmail.com";
if (badWordList.Any(w => myText.IndexOf(w, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
{
    // How to remove
}
```

Below is the set of input of expected output:

1. i/p- email:abc@gmail.com

   o/p - abc@gmail.com
2. i/p- Jack F. Mobile:89788987

   o/p- Jack F. 89788987
3. i/p- Jack F. Email:t@p.c mobile:65777 WEB

   o/p- Jack F. t@p.c 65777

I would prefer a non-regex approach. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any problem with Regex? That is always faster and more convenient.

Comment: `myText = myText.Replace(badWordList.First(i => myText.IndexOf(w, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0), "");` Generally, if this is going to handle user-input, be sure that it won't.

Comment: @Kangkan: No problem with Regex.

Comment: @PLB Answers should not be put as a comment, however simple the answer is, it is an answer.

Comment: @PhilipGullick This is not a solution because it will fail in many cases, won't be helpful for future readers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove substring from a list of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058046/remove-substring-from-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can iterate on the bad words and remove them:

```
foreach (string badWord in badWordList) {
    myText = myText.Replace(badWord, string.Empty);
}
```

If you need a case-insensitive solution you can use the overload with a `StringComparison` parameter:

```
myText = myText.Replace(badWord, string.Empty, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

*Note*: a previous version of this answer, which is quite old, and some of the comments to this question, suggested to use a Regex for a case-insensitive string replacement (see example below).
I think that now that there is the overload with the `StringComparison` it's much better to just use that.

```
string myText = "EMAIL:abc@gmail.com";
Regex badWords = new Regex("email:|index|mobile:|fax:|web", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
myText = badWords.Replace(myText, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can remove strings by replacing them with the empty string:

```
foreach (var badWord in badWordList)
{
    myText = myText.Replace(badWord, "");
}
```

Unfortulately this is case sensitive. For case-insensitive string replace without regular expressions, see [Is there a case insensitive string replace in .Net without using Regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5549426/50079)

You can also do it with a regular expression, in which case case-insensitive comparison comes "for free":

```
var regex = String.Join("|", badWordList.Select(w => Regex.Escape(w)));
var myText = Regex.replace(myText, regex, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: At beginning, I thought I would go with non-regex approach. But now, I think Regex will be much helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the instance of the 'bad word' with `string.Empty`: -

```
List<string> badWordList = new List<string> { "email", "index:", "mobile:", "fax:", "web" };
string myText = "email:abc@gmail.com";

foreach (string s in badWordList)
{
    myText = myText.Replace(s,string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Only thing I'd say is the `IndexOf` check is unnecessary, since `.Replace` won't replace anything if `string` given to it does not exist in the other string.

Answer (score 1):

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Collections;
            namespace WindowMaker
            {
                class Program
                {

                    static void Main(string[] args)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Enter Main string...");
                        String str = System.Console.ReadLine();
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Enter sub string...");
                        String sub = System.Console.ReadLine();
                        Boolean flag;
                        int strlen=sub.Length;
                        int inde = str.IndexOf(sub);
                        while (inde != -1)
                        {
                            inde = str.IndexOf(sub);
                            str=str.Replace(sub,"");

                        }
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Remaining string :: {0}",str);

                            Console.Read();
                    }

                }
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if it is case sensitive :

```
List<String> badWordList = new List<String> { "email:", "index", "mobile:", "fax:", "web" };
String myText = "This is a exemple of Email: deleting with index and fax and web";

badWordList.ForEach(bw => myText = myText.Replace(bw, String.Empty));
```